# Intersections in 3d model

Tags: bevel

How can I remove some intersections in my model?
They cause wrong slicing for my printer.
The model consists of a path curve and a profile curve.
I use the bevel in the path curve with the object the profile curve.
I use Blender 2.8.
Thanks.

[image: Intersections]

Comment: In 2.82 builds there is a voxel remesher inside mesh tab, it can deal with intersections.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find out the documentation for using it?

Comment: It's a development build, so not that much info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/retopology.html

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.81 adds support for the Voxel Remesh operator, which can efficiently get rid of intersecting geometry such as meshes generated by tightly turning or self-intersecting beveled curves, for example this one:

[image: self-intersecting beveled curve with extra tight turns]

The step by step process goes like this:

1. Ensure that the endpoints are capped - you can manually add faces later but since you are using a profile curve anyway, it's easy to add caps right here:

[image: Caps!]

2. Convert the curve to mesh: Object -> Convert to -> Mesh From Curve/Surf/Meta/Text.
3. Press F3 (operator search) -> type "Voxel Remesh"

[image]

The result should now be something like this. Note that there are visible "welds" because the voxel resolution is not too big.

[image]

To adjust the parameters for the voxels, select the mesh, enter sculpt mode,

[image]

Then on the properties window adjust the settings for the remesh operation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the curve's radius or decrease the radius of the bevel object. In short, the second one cannot be bigger than the first. An alternative is to make the curve with bezier curves and extrude it (Extrude in Curve Geometry tab).To convert it to mesh, and extrude+scale. Add bevel to round.

Comment: I know it :) But I cannot do it! If I do it the geometry of my model will change. It will be wrong for me... Is there another way?